# Posting string data to Web API with AngularJS results in null

Tags: angularjs, http, post

I'm using AngularJS v1.2.25. When I post a payload data (string) to my Web API via POST I always get null. I tried it with Postman (REST client), then I get a string. I was wondering whether this is a bug, because the typeof variable is string.

Here's my HTTP request (using Fiddler) from Postman:

```
POST http://localhost:60858/logout HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:60858
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 90
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: chrome-extension://fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,is;q=0.6
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=wox5u5pt5k0ox2hkontz53q4; .ASPXANONYMOUS=2CsdBwYO0AEkAAAAOTg3MDRkMjQtZmE4OC00OTE3LWE2NWYtMDk4ODY4MzA0Y2ZlgxJyUfsE9kDSzQ5edZ4FaUrI1djayGn3QfiUK9J4Ko01

"Ge8KFyOASBV8EbbbKJFrj8vkfZy0BYQZmvGrksFTPtesPvIAMvonRyr0qXNJGM18QxROI6s+26L/z/uOhSbJYA=="
```

Here's my actual HTTP request (via $http in AngularJS):

```
POST http://localhost:60858/logout HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:60858
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 88
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:53998
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost:53998/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,is;q=0.6

Ge8KFyOASBV8EbbbKJFrj8vkfZy0BYQZmvGrksFTPtesPvIAMvonRyr0qXNJGM18QxROI6s+26L/z/uOhSbJYA==
```

Code where I'm using the $http method:

```
return $http[method](fullpath, data);
```

Code where I'm receiving the payload (string) in the Web API:

```
[Route("logout")]
[HttpPost]
public bool Logout([FromBody] string accessToken)
{
    var logout = _userService.LogUserOut(accessToken);
    return logout;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code where you are using the $http service?

Comment: Updated my post. `data` was a string (see above), but is sent raw over the wire.

Comment: Please be aware $http use promise. For example: $http.get('http://getchicken.com').success(function(data){}).error(errorHandlerCb);

Comment: @MikeNQ I'm aware of that. This is inside a function, then I use `func().success(function(data) {});`. But please focus on the problem in OP.

Comment: Then could you post the code where your server handle the request. Also, just to confirm, you mean that data is null, yes?

Comment: Correct. Updated OP.

Comment: Is data a string or an object? If it's a string try changing it to : `{ accessToken: data }`

Comment: It's a string. This didn't work. I added a check `if(typeof data === 'string') data = '"' + data + '"';`. That works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding quotes `""` around the data string works.

```
if(typeof data === 'string') data = '"' + data + '"';
```